# How to create a group on an existing HDF5 file? (HDF5)

Tags: c#, hdf5

I have a 3rd party utility written in C++ that creates an HDF5 file with a single data group.

I would like to import two H5 files each with a unique data group, and output a single H5 file with the two data groups.

Does anyone have experience with working with HDF5 in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just writing a command line utility that drives the precompiled HDF5 utilities.  Using H5Copy you can selectively copy groups from one h5 file to another.